# Using Selenium WebDriver, how do I click on the SET button in the Android data picker dialog?

Tags: android, selenium, testing, datepicker, webdriver

My browser application is running in Chrome in Android Samsung Galaxy S10. After clicking the data field on the web page, a date picker dialog is shown. I just leave whatever default date is selected.

I just want to click the SET button as shown in the image below. tried the CSS button[text="SET"] and also the javascript way of clicking on this SET button or link, and it is not working. I get an error "element not found".

Is this SET link in the date picker dialog comes from the browser or is it a date component of Android OS? What command should be used to click on the SET button?

[image]

Comment: Is the date picker in an iframe?

Comment: it is not an iFrame. once I click the date field, the control goes to the Android OS and it shows its native calendar datePickerDialog.